# What is diffrence between importing angular module at top of the file and importing it in function parameter

Tags: angular

I have a component and I have implemented OnInit, OnChanges interfaces

**OnInit** and **OnChanges** are imported from `'@angular/core'` at the top of file.

like below

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
```

But when I try to implement OnChanges interfaces using Visual Studio shortcut like below

[image]

It had added method like below

[image]

So I couldnt understand the diffrence between below cases:

**case 1:** importing `SimpleChanges`  at top of file

```
import { SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
```

**Case 2:** importing `SimpleChanges` in function parameter

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: import("@angular/core").SimpleChanges): void {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference: importing SimpleChanges at top of file makes it visible for all code in the file. Importing as function argument makes it visible only for function. Visual studio code generator goes on the way of minimal impact and side effects of generated code.